# Why does spark spin more executors than available cores on the machine?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

[image: spark should have spinned 6 containers instead of 9 below]

I often see that spark spins more executors than it should on a given node. This is spiking the load average on the node which eventually results in `executor lost` or `bad node` or `unhealthy node`

My spark configuration is as follows

1. each node: 8cores, 32GB; `yarn. node manager.resource.cpu-vcores` on master, core, and task nodes is set to 6. Meaning at most 6 executors should run on a node.
2. Few jobs run with 2cores, 8GB; and few with 1core 2GB; --meaning Even in the worst case one node should at most spin 6 containers. However (above image) I see that 9 containers are spun.
3. On ganglia I see that the nodes are at 19 load average (while the node has only 8vcores) --because of this high load average the executors are getting lost (the driver can't get heartbeats on time; executors run slowly because of high load averages)
4. We are using EMR 6.9; Spark 3.2.0

Questions:

1. Why did Spark spin more executors than configured?
2. Is it possible to limit the max executors to 6 in this case?
3. On another node 5 cores and 25GB is available, yet why didn't spark/ yarn choose to spin executors there?

[image: spark could have spinned new executors here instead]

My startup configuration JSON file to AWS-EMR is as follows. This was given to the node configurations for master, task, and core nodes (same JSON to all).

I added high values to heartbeats etc. only to make sure executors are not lost. A job runs for 1-1.5 hrs; if only the executor can hang on for a while the job is completed, or else all 1.5 hrs effort is wasted.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores": "6",
      "yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb": "30000",
      "yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-max-ms":"60000",
      "yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-min-ms":"60000",
      "yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms":"60000",
      "yarn.nodemanager.health-checker.timeout-ms":"72000000",
      "yarn.nodemanager.health-checker.interval-ms":"36000000",
      "yarn.resourcemanager.application-timeouts.monitor.interval-ms":"180000"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "mapred-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.app.mapreduce.am.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms":"60000",
      "yarn.app.mapreduce.am.hard-kill-timeout-ms":"600000"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval": "600s",
      "spark.network.timeout":"7200s"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find the fix. Apparently `capacity-scheduler` of yarn has bug which does over allocation of executors when there is adequate memory for new executor. Now, this can be fixed by setting the flag

```
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"
```

in /capacity-scheduler.conf

In my case because I am using EMR the below configuration helped.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores": "5"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "capacity-scheduler",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"
    }
  }
]
```

With the above JSON, I verified and now Yarn doesn't allocate more than configured cores on the node to the executors.

steps:
( new emr console > select cluster > configurations > instance group configurations > select master radio > reconfigure > and then give the above json > save )