# How is my total executor cores more than total cores in cluster of spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am using AWS EMR for running spark with 1 instance of master node (m6g.xlarge) and 1 instance of slave node (m6g.2xlarge).
m6g.2xlarge has 8 vCpu, default cpu cores.

I am running spark with following configurations.
`--executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 2`

Ideally according to my knowledge, total cores in cluster are 8. and Total cores requested by my configuration is `3x2 = 6`. so at the most 2 executors should be added by cluster manager. 2 cores are left for daemon processes.

[image]

But what I see is 3 executors being added with total cores `3x3=9`, how is that possible?

Comment: Please find my spark submit command * spark-submit --deploy-mode client --conf spark.ui.enabled=true --driver-memory 12g --driver-cores 4 --executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 3 --num-executors 2 *

Comment: In dynamic allocation mode, `--num-executors` defines the _initial_ number of executors. You'd need to set `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=2` to limit the total number, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation.

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha, but my question is how is it using more number of cores than actual available in cluster.

Comment: [Why does spark spin more executors than available cores on the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065178/why-does-spark-spin-more-executors-than-available-cores-on-the-machine) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are a bit confused with the name "cores" here.
There is no strict dependency between physical cores and "executor cores".

Simply put, in Spark jargon, "executor" means JVM, and "core" means thread inside the JVM. Obviously, you can have much more threads than physical cores so nothing wrong (or unexpected) in your scenario.

BTW, in Databricks to avoid such confusion it is [recommended](https://files.training.databricks.com/courses/ilt/Spark-ILT/Spark-ILT-5.1.1/amazon/instructor-notes/Spark%20Architecture.html) to instructors to use the term "thread" or "slot" instead of "core".